# Adding an assert statement inside a test case, for an API service which returns void?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

I am trying to write a test case for an API service which deletes a particular record from the database. The test works fine , but i'm not sure what assert statement to add to my test case. As the code changes go through a sonarqube quality gate build , assert statements are mandatory for all unit test cases.

Here is my code:

```
@Test
    public void delete() throws Exception {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(fragmentResponse);
        when(fragmentRepository.get(anyString())).thenReturn(fragments);
        fragmentService.delete("history", "es");

}
```

As the fragment service returns void, i am unsure about what assert statement to add at the end of it.

Comment: Query the data afterwards and check that what you wanted to delete is no longer there - and / or verify that the delete call to whatever mocked layer below was properly made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert the repository method responsible for deletion is called.

`verify(fragmentRepository, times(1)).delete(fragments);`